# What is the terminus of the AUMF?

Tags: united-states, military

Does the [AUMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_for_Use_of_Military_Force_Against_Terrorists)  authorization expire upon a certain condition or is it indefinite?  If not indefinite, at what point would it be terminated?

Comment: The full text of the statute is right there in the Wikipedia article - did you read it?  There is no mention of expiration.

Answer (score 1):

The operative language of the AUMF (from the link in the question) says:

> That the President is authorized to use all necessary and appropriate
>   force against **those nations, organizations, or persons he determines
>   planned, authorized, committed, or aided the terrorist attacks that
>   occurred on September 11, 2001, or harbored such organizations or
>   persons,** in order to prevent any future acts of international
>   terrorism against the United States by such nations, organizations or
>   persons.

So, it ends when all such nations, organization or persons no longer exist, or upon passage of a law repealing the AUMF. These nations or organizations would include the Taliban, and have been determined to include ISIS, so until both of those organizations are no more, the AUMF is arguably still in force.